# Build grafana docker image from the source

Tags: docker, dockerfile, grafana

I'm trying to build grafana docker image from the branch `release-10.1.1` in the AWS Linux server with `t3.large` and it gets hanged here:

```
 => [js-builder 12/12] RUN yarn build                                                                                                   151.0s
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% sealing chunk assets processing                                                                           
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% sealing chunk assets processing                                                                           
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing                                                                                  
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing copy-webpack-plugin                                                              
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing PersistentChildCompilerSingletonPlugin                                           
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% sealing asset processing EsbuildPlugin                                                                    
 => CACHED [go-builder  2/19] RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then       apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git;     fi                 0.0s
 => CACHED [go-builder  3/19] WORKDIR /tmp/grafana                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [go-builder  4/19] COPY go.* ./                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [go-builder  5/19] COPY .bingo .bingo                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [go-builder  6/19] RUN go mod download                                                                                         0.0s
 => [go-builder  7/19] COPY embed.go Makefile build.go package.json ./                                                                    0.1s
 => [go-builder  8/19] COPY cue.mod cue.mod                                                                                               0.0s
 => [go-builder  9/19] COPY kinds kinds                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [go-builder 10/19] COPY local local                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [go-builder 11/19] COPY packages/grafana-schema packages/grafana-schema                                                               0.1s
 => [go-builder 12/19] COPY public/app/plugins public/app/plugins                                                                         0.7s
 => [go-builder 13/19] COPY public/api-merged.json public/api-merged.json                                                                 0.1s
 => [go-builder 14/19] COPY pkg pkg                                                                                                       3.2s
 => [go-builder 15/19] COPY scripts scripts                                                                                               0.1s
 => [go-builder 16/19] COPY conf conf                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [go-builder 17/19] COPY .github .github                                                                                               0.1s
 => [go-builder 18/19] COPY LICENSE ./                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [go-builder 19/19] RUN make build-go GO_BUILD_TAGS=oss WIRE_TAGS=oss                                                                146.5s
 => => # (re)installing /go/bin/wire-v0.5.0                                                                                                   
 => => # go: downloading github.com/google/subcommands v1.0.1                                                                                 
 => => # go: downloading github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0                                                                                 
 => => # go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190422233926-fe54fb35175b                                                                
 => => # generate go files                                                                                                                    
 => => # /go/bin/wire-v0.5.0 gen -tags oss ./pkg/server
```

The Dockerfile is below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG BASE_IMAGE=alpine:3.17
ARG JS_IMAGE=node:18-alpine3.17
ARG JS_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
ARG GO_IMAGE=golang:1.20.6-alpine3.17

ARG GO_SRC=go-builder
ARG JS_SRC=js-builder

FROM --platform=${JS_PLATFORM} ${JS_IMAGE} as js-builder

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8000

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

COPY package.json yarn.lock .yarnrc.yml ./
COPY .yarn .yarn
COPY packages packages
COPY plugins-bundled plugins-bundled

RUN yarn install --immutable

COPY tsconfig.json .eslintrc .editorconfig .browserslistrc .prettierrc.js babel.config.json .linguirc ./
COPY public public
COPY scripts scripts
COPY emails emails

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn build

FROM ${GO_IMAGE} as go-builder

ARG COMMIT_SHA=""
ARG BUILD_BRANCH=""
ARG GO_BUILD_TAGS="oss"
ARG WIRE_TAGS="oss"
ARG BINGO="true"

# Install build dependencies
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git; \
    fi

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

COPY go.* ./
COPY .bingo .bingo

RUN go mod download
#RUN if [[ "$BINGO" = "true" ]]; then \
#      go install github.com/bwplotka/bingo@latest && \
#      bingo get -v; \
#    fi

COPY embed.go Makefile build.go package.json ./
COPY cue.mod cue.mod
COPY kinds kinds
COPY local local
COPY packages/grafana-schema packages/grafana-schema
COPY public/app/plugins public/app/plugins
COPY public/api-merged.json public/api-merged.json
COPY pkg pkg
COPY scripts scripts
COPY conf conf
COPY .github .github
COPY LICENSE ./

ENV COMMIT_SHA=${COMMIT_SHA}
ENV BUILD_BRANCH=${BUILD_BRANCH}

RUN make build-go GO_BUILD_TAGS=${GO_BUILD_TAGS} WIRE_TAGS=${WIRE_TAGS}

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as tgz-builder

WORKDIR /tmp/grafana

ARG GRAFANA_TGZ="grafana-latest.linux-x64-musl.tar.gz"

COPY ${GRAFANA_TGZ} /tmp/grafana.tar.gz

# add -v to make tar print every file it extracts
RUN tar x -z -f /tmp/grafana.tar.gz --strip-components=1

# helpers for COPY --from
FROM ${GO_SRC} as go-src
FROM ${JS_SRC} as js-src

# Final stage
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

LABEL maintainer="Grafana Labs <hello@grafana.com>"

ARG GF_UID="472"
ARG GF_GID="0"

ENV PATH="/usr/share/grafana/bin:$PATH" \
    GF_PATHS_CONFIG="/etc/grafana/grafana.ini" \
    GF_PATHS_DATA="/var/lib/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_HOME="/usr/share/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_LOGS="/var/log/grafana" \
    GF_PATHS_PLUGINS="/var/lib/grafana/plugins" \
    GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING="/etc/grafana/provisioning"

WORKDIR $GF_PATHS_HOME

# Install dependencies
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      apk add --no-cache ca-certificates bash curl tzdata musl-utils && \
      apk info -vv | sort; \
    elif grep -i -q ubuntu /etc/issue; then \
      DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
      apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl tzdata musl && \
      apt-get autoremove -y && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    else \
      echo 'ERROR: Unsupported base image' && /bin/false; \
    fi

# glibc support for alpine x86_64 only
RUN if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue && [ `arch` = "x86_64" ]; then \
      wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
      wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.35-r0/glibc-2.35-r0.apk \
        -O /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk && \
      wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.35-r0/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk \
        -O /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      apk add --force-overwrite --no-cache /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      ln -s /usr/glibc-compat/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      rm -f /tmp/glibc-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /tmp/glibc-bin-2.35-r0.apk && \
      rm -f /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
      rm -f /etc/ld.so.cache; \
    fi

COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/conf ./conf

RUN if [ ! $(getent group "$GF_GID") ]; then \
      if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
        addgroup -S -g $GF_GID grafana; \
      else \
        addgroup --system --gid $GF_GID grafana; \
      fi; \
    fi && \
    GF_GID_NAME=$(getent group $GF_GID | cut -d':' -f1) && \
    mkdir -p "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" && \
    if grep -i -q alpine /etc/issue; then \
      adduser -S -u $GF_UID -G "$GF_GID_NAME" grafana; \
    else \
      adduser --system --uid $GF_UID --ingroup "$GF_GID_NAME" grafana; \
    fi && \
    mkdir -p "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/datasources" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/dashboards" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/notifiers" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/plugins" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/access-control" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING/alerting" \
             "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" \
             "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" \
             "$GF_PATHS_DATA" && \
    cp conf/sample.ini "$GF_PATHS_CONFIG" && \
    cp conf/ldap.toml /etc/grafana/ldap.toml && \
    chown -R "grafana:$GF_GID_NAME" "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING" && \
    chmod -R 777 "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_HOME/.aws" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS" "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" "$GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING"

COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/bin/grafana* /tmp/grafana/bin/*/grafana* ./bin/
COPY --from=js-src /tmp/grafana/public ./public
COPY --from=go-src /tmp/grafana/LICENSE ./

EXPOSE 3000

ARG RUN_SH=./packaging/docker/run.sh

COPY ${RUN_SH} /run.sh

USER "$GF_UID"
ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]
```

Does anyone can explain whats the issue here and provide a solution for the issue?

Thank you.

This is explained in the question and I expect to build the docker image in a clean way.